# Pig if-else condition

Tags: if-statement, apache-pig, conditional-statements

I have a file, that I'm loading to pig and doing some nice work on it. Everything goes smoothly until I reach to the point in which I need to use a condition, a kind of if-else statement. I want to check if the variable **syn** is not blank, in which case (if TRUE) the value would be 1, else it would be 0.

Here's the code

```
B = foreach A generate t, (syn!='' ? 1 : 0) as s;
```

The command runs without a glitch but when i dump the results, this happens:

```
(8758.414086,)
(8758.457255,1)
```

So when the condition is TRUE the value is added to B. But, I cannot seem to understand why on earth the else part is being left out, instead of adding the 0. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** for anyone interested I found a solution, although the original question remains. Instead of the `==` operator, I used

`B = foreach A generate t, (syn is not null ? 1 : 0) as s;`

and it worked like a charm. However my question remains.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here:[1](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#nulls)

> **Nulls and Load Functions**
> The Pig Latin load functions (for example, PigStorage and TextLoader) produce null values wherever data is missing. For example, empty strings (chararrays) are not loaded; instead, they are replaced by nulls.
>
> **Comparison operators**
> If either subexpression is null, the result is null.

So, if you prefer empty strings to load as '' instead of null, you need a custom loader.